# how to serialize an object into and save it to mysql database?

Tags: java, android, sql

i want to store a list of timestamps in android sqlite database.

like :

```
CREATE TABLE NOTEBOOK(
TITLES VARCHAR(50),
PHONE_NUMBERS INTEGER(11),
LIST_OF_RELATED_DATES TIMESTAMP[50]
)
```

Comment: Is this a codegolf? ***:)***

Comment: Is it so hard to google and make effort in research? [SQlite creating a database with a timestamp column and adding a value in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596126/sqlite-creating-a-database-with-a-timestamp-column-and-adding-a-value-in)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQlite creating a database with a timestamp column and adding a value in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596126/sqlite-creating-a-database-with-a-timestamp-column-and-adding-a-value-in)

Comment: store them as a string, serialized JSON, serialized XML...

Comment: why the down votes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - simply text type column can be used to store timestamp. Once it will retrieve from the database it can parse in long type as required.
For example:

`long timeStamp = 1456789985674L;`


`//To save timestamp in database(SQLite)
 String dataBaseValue = String.valueOf(timeStamp);`


`//To fetch timestamp in database(SQLite)
 timeStamp = Long.valueOf(dataBaseValue);`


`//timeStamp can be used as per requirements.`

Comment: thanks  i serialize them

Comment: Ur Welcome, glad that you have done!