# Creating a view that joins multiple tables on an ID and a timestamp that needs to be rounded

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a web application that sends data to my sqlite database into different tables depending on the information. I would like to make a view that merges multiple tables together based on cownumber and TS[timestamp] (There are no updates to my table, so a change to the same cownumber send the full record as a new entry with a new timestamp). The ajax calls are made table by table so the TS do not exactly sync up generally they can be  5-20 seconds off depending on the connection

Here is a sample of the three tables

```
+----master_animal-----+
+----------------------------------------------------+
| cownumber | height   | weight | ts                 |
+-----------+----------+--------+--------------------+
| 1         | 150      | ...    | 2017-12-01 12:28:00|
| 2         | 170      | ...    | 2017-12-03 17:16:00|
| 3         | 60       | ...    | 2017-12-03 08:09:00|
| 4         | 109      | ...    | 2017-12-04 23:23:00|


+----animal_inventory-----+
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| cownumber | brandlocation| dateacquired| ts                 |
+-----------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 1         | ...          | ...         | 2017-12-01 12:28:50|
| 2         | ...          | ...         | 2017-12-03 17:16:30|
| 3         | ...          | ...         | 2017-12-03 08:09:12|
| 4         |  ...         | ...         | 2017-12-04 23:23:23|

+----experiment-----+
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| cownumber | ageatwean    | birthweight | ts                 |
+-----------+--------------+-------------+--------------------+
| 1         | ...          | ...         | 2017-12-01 12:28:20|
| 2         | ...          | ...         | 2017-12-03 17:16:41|
| 3         | ...          | ...         | 2017-12-03 08:09:24|
| 4         |  ...         | ...         | 2017-12-04 23:23:11|
```

The View I wrote

```
CREATE VIEW testing
AS SELECT a.height,a.weight,a.cownumber,
b.brandlocation,b.dateacquired,
c.ageatwean,c.birthweight
FROM master_animal a, animal_inventory b, experiment c
WHERE a.cownumber=b.cownumber
AND ROUND(a.ts/10000) = ROUND(b.ts/10000)
AND a.cownumber=c.cownumber
AND ROUND(a.ts/10000) = ROUND(c.ts/10000);
```

The query I wrote

```
Select * from testing where cownumber = 1;
```

What I was hoping to get back was

```
+----testing-----+
+----------------------------------------------------+
| cownumber | height | weight | brandlocation| dateacquired | ageatwean |birthweight | 
+-----------+--------+--------+--------------+--------------+-----------+------------+
| 941        | 0     | ...    |       ...    |     ...      |     ...   |   ..       |
```

Where there will be one row for cownumber 941 as long as all the correlated records were within a few seconds of each other. I am not exactly sure if I need to divide by 10000 or smaller. The same record should be no more than 50 seconds apart from each other. Anything more than 50 seconds apart should be considered a new record.

When I test this where there is only one record for that cownumber it works fine. But lets say I change some information from each table. I provide a new height, a new brandlocation.

Instead of getting two rows. The first row being the initial data entry and the second row showing the same cownumber with the changed values, I get back 8 rows with partial changes.

```
height|weight|cownumber|brandlocation|dateacquired|ageatwean|birthweight|
0.0|0.0|941|0|0|0.0|0
0.0|0.0|941|0|0|0.0|0
0.0|0.0|941|Left Hip|0|0.0|0
0.0|0.0|941|Left Hip|0|0.0|0
50.0|0.0|941|0|0|0.0|0
50.0|0.0|941|0|0|0.0|0
50.0|0.0|941|Left Hip|0|0.0|0
50.0|0.0|941|Left Hip|0|0.0|0
```

I assume the issue is in my where clause but I am not sure exactly how to fix it

Comment: I dont see repeat on your cows. Where are the insert updates?

Comment: The inserts are done by ajax POST on the client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timestamps are stored as strings. When you try to divide it, the database tries to convert it to a number, which results in `2017`. So all timestamps end up being the same.

Dividing cannot determine the distance; the values 9999 and 10000 will end up different although they are right near each other. (And an integer division results in an integer result, so the `ROUND()` has no effect.)

To compute the distance, convert the timestamp into a number of seconds first, and then use [abs()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#abs):

```
SELECT ...
FROM master_animal m
JOIN animal_inventory i ON m.cownumber = i.cownumber
                       AND abs(strftime('%s', m.ts) - strftime('%s', i.ts)) <= 50
JOIN experiment e       ON m.cownumber = e.cownumber
                       AND abs(strftime('%s', m.ts) - strftime('%s', e.ts)) <= 50;
```

Comment: why you say are strings? the OP say are timestamps

Comment: I used the timestamp variable in sql  when I made them. But looking at this makes me think that what youa re saying makes more sense. SQLite just stores them as strings anyway. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596126/sqlite-creating-a-database-with-a-timestamp-column-and-adding-a-value-in                            I will try your method and get back to you if it works. Thanks